# R: Matrix sorting by only part of a column

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a matrix, say:

```
c <- c(1,2,3,4,5,0,1,-5,3,1,-3,2,-2,1,2,0,1,0,3,3,5,-5,3,-1,0)
M <- matrix(c, byrow=T, nrow=5)
M
```

So:

```
M
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    0    1   -5    3    1
[3,]   -3    2   -2    1    2
[4,]    0    1    0    3    3
[5,]    5   -5    3   -1    0
```

I know how to sort M by **absolute values** of column [,3] (for example):

```
Ma <- abs(M)
Ms <- M[order(Ma[,3], decreasing = T),]
Ms
```

So:

```
Ms
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1   -5    3    1
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    5   -5    3   -1    0
[4,]   -3    2   -2    1    2
[5,]    0    1    0    3    3
```

But what I would like to have is M sorted not by the entire column [,3], but only by **the last 3 absolute values**, so that the first two lines of M are not changed:

```
Ms
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    0    1   -5    3    1
[3,]    5   -5    3   -1    0
[4,]   -3    2   -2    1    2
[5,]    0    1    0    3    3
```

I couldn't find how to do this in a simple way. Any idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: Well, thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
M[(nrow(M)-2):nrow(M),] <- tail(M,3)[order(tail(Ma[,3],3), decreasing=TRUE),]
M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#[2,]    0    1   -5    3    1
#[3,]    5   -5    3   -1    0
#[4,]   -3    2   -2    1    2
#[5,]    0    1    0    3    3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
M[c(1:2,2L+order(abs(M[-1:-2,3L]),decreasing=T)),];
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
## [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
## [2,]    0    1   -5    3    1
## [3,]    5   -5    3   -1    0
## [4,]   -3    2   -2    1    2
## [5,]    0    1    0    3    3
```